# Simulate query of larger size

Tags: sql-server

I need to execute larger size query on sql server. 
Is there any way to simulate a query of larger size (around 10000 bytes) to be executed on sql server?

Comment: how do you estimate the size of a query? the size is the length of the query?

Comment: do you just need 10000 bytes of code on the sql regardless complexity?

Comment: By size of query I mean the length of query regardless of complexity

Comment: maybe you forgot to explain something but... what's wrong with cut&paste the same fields over and over in a statement like `select field1,field2,field1,field2,field1,field2,...,fieldN from anytable` up to 10000 bytes?

Comment: I tried that but there seems to be a restriction of 128 bytes on server

Comment: The maximum batch size in SQL Server is 64K times the network packet size (4K default), which calculates to 256MB.  If you are having a problem with batches over 128 bytes, let us know how you are building and executing the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to QUOTED_IDENTIFIER. I was passing a string to select statement in double quotes so the limitation was coming up. But executing the same query in single quotes worked.

```
sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic208737-8-1.aspx
```

Thank you all for quick replies